# ALSA set plughw as default

Tags: audio, alsa, usb-audio

I have a USB audio device, configured as the default device at card 0.

I have a 3rd party application that is attempting to play wav files, which fail with the following:

```
Playing WAVE 'sound.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 44100 Hz, Mono
aplay: set_params:1239: Channels count non available
```

If I try to manually play the very same wav, I get no error but also no sound:

```
aplay sound.wav
Playing WAVE 'sound.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 44100 Hz, Mono
```

If I specify device `plughw:0,0`, the sound plays correctly!

```
aplay -D plughw:0,0 sound.wav
Playing WAVE 'sound.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 44100 Hz, Mono
```

I have tried various attemps at configuring `~/.asoundrc` to set `plughw:0,0` as the default, without success.

How can I apply the `-D plughw:0,0` be default to all sound playback?

Comment: That 3rd-party app calls `aplay`, and uses some wrong parameter(s). Can you configure it somehow? Otherwise, you have to find out what happens there; try replacing `/usr/bin/aplay` with a script that logs its parameters.

Comment: Please explain in detail what 3rd party application you use, what ALSA device it uses, and if you can configure it to use other devices. Without any `~/.asoundrc`, the `default` device already is equivalent to `plughw` + `dmix`, so there's probably nothing you can do in your `~/.asoundrc` alone.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Backup your ~/.asoundrc - if you have one - and add the following, to a new  **~/.asoundrc**:

```
pcm.!default { 
 type plug 
 slave { 
 pcm "hw:0,0" 
 } 
}
```