# Alsa: set default PCM

Tags: alsa

My Lenovo x1 Gen4 has an Intel "Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio" and I'm trying to record audio through the onboard mic.

In Alsa "List all PCMs" (arecord -L) show many different PCM's (for my one sound card). Selecting a certaine one ("plughw:CARD=PCH,DEV=0") in arecord works, the other PCM's do not work.

So I'm either looking for a way to change the default pcm to  plughw, or to have Pulseaudio pick my working alsa PCM.

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/360304/alsa-set-plughw-as-default) seems to come close to what I need, but in playback rather than recording.

Anything I can try or hints in the right direction are most welcome, thanks in advance!

Comment: PulseAudio ignores most of the ALSA configuration; the default device must be set in, e.g., `pavucontrol`.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. In pavucontrol the input device is not shown. ("No input devices available") I'm completely out of my depth I'm afraid. Anything I can do/try/read?

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question:

cat ~/.asoundrc

```
pcm.!default { 
 type plug 
 slave { 
 pcm "plughw:0,0" 
 } 
}
```